# How to run the autoware runtime manager through carla_autoware?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i run the autoware runtime manager through the carla_autoware. I have followed and run this https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla-autoware and drive the vehicle around and all. But now i would like to run the  runtime manager interface to upload different map, pcd, waypoints etc.. Also is there a way to create/ upload new waypoint files  through rviz or ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366811/how-to-run-the-autoware-runtime-manager-through-carla_autoware?/) by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `carla_autoware` project creates a Docker container in which Autoware is run. Inside this Docker container, you can source the Autoware installation as normal (e.g. `source /home/autoware/Autoware/install/setup.bash`) and run the `runtime_manager` with `ros2 launch runtime_manager runtime_manager`.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0